# How to fix 401 after attempt to override existing POST?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm receiving 401 error when trying to override existing POST with new data. It throws 401. As I could observe it is xmlhttprequest. Code and screen of chrome console:

[image]

```
const send = function(method,url,data){
    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url)
        xhr.responseType = "json"
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.onload = function(){
            resolve(xhr.response)
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
    });
    return promise;
};

const final = function(){
    send("POST", "https://www.thecrims.com/api/v1/input",{
        email:"yes",
        password:"no"
    }).then(function(responseData){
        console.log(responseData)
    });
};
```

Comment: error 401 means you are not authorized, the issue is rather server-side (unless you have credentials and forgot to include the proper headers in the request)

Comment: I run this code straight from console after logging in. So it might be headers realted issue then ?

Comment: you should send the request with all credentials required. The proper way to do it depends on the API you are targetting (ask the webmaster) ; it can be authentication headers or tokens sent in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Url you are trying to access require authentication. you need to provide specific authentication to access the URL. Get those from server side and implement it here.